# How to observe output volume in background on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, background, avaudiosession

I have an issue with observing output volume in background, apparently because audio session become inactive, when app enter background. I already turn on background mode for audio in project settings, it didn't help.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try? audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
        try? audioSession.setActive(true)
        audioSession.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "outputVolume", options: .new, context: nil)
}

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print(AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume)
    }
}
```

Comment: An app does not have access to audio sessions other than its own, and in general will not run arbitrary code unless in the foreground. You will need to address your problem in a different way.

Comment: Found in close queue review.  "you can't do that" is not a valid reason to close a question.  Answering explaining why someone cannot accomplish their goal seems more beneficial for the community.